# ¿Cómo asignar una función en Html a un botón?

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel, funciones

El problema es el siguiente ....

Tengo una consulta de una EXCEL, la cual de inicio la descargo, seleccionándola en el directorio de mi disco duro y por mediación de un botón muestro su contenido.
Y espero a que se pulse un botón para procesar la información mostrada, para actualizar una tabla en mi base de datos.

El caso es que este segundo botón debe llamar a la rutina para volver a leer esa EXCEL y actualizar la tabla, le he dado vueltas al problema y no doy con ello.

Si hago la actualización en el mismo momento de presentar la información la primera vez se actualiza sin problemas .

```html
<?php
$util = new util();
check_session(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$util = new util();
define('EOL', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../clases/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
/** todo pendiente: poder seleccionar la version de excell, 2005, 2007, etc */
function actualizo($ficherofinal)
 {   if (file_exists($ficherofinal))
  { 
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($ficherofinal);
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
  foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
  {  
   for ($i = 9; $i <= $numRows; $i++) 
   {
   $serie = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
   $id_factu = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
....
   $referencia_cobro = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
   $estado_e = 1;
   actualizo2( $id_factu, $numero_factura, $estado_e, $fecha_factura, $referencia_cobro);
   }
  } 
  }
 };

function actualizo2( $id_factu, $numero_factura, $estado_e, $fecha_factura, $referencia_cobro)
  {
       $util = new util();
      $t_lineas=array('id_factu', 'numero_factura', 'estado_e', 'fecha_factura', 'referencia_cobro');
            $values = array( $id_factu, $numero_factura, $estado_e, $fecha_factura, $referencia_cobro);
   $wherelistado = "factusol.lineas_facturadas.id_factu = '". $id_factu. "'";
   $result = $util->update('factusol.lineas_facturadas', $t_lineas, $values, $wherelistado );
  };
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>

  (aqui hay mas parte del programa)
  
  .....
    </div>
    <div style="text-aign: center">
    <input type="submit" id="consultar" name="consultar" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:26px;" value=" Consultar "  onclick="comprueba();" > 
    <input type="button"  id="mostrar" name="mostrar"  class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:26px;" onclick="actualizo(<?php echo $ficherofinal;?>)"  value=" Actualizar registros? "> 
    </div>

......

    <div id="content" class="padding-20">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="panel-body" id="pedirdatos">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
               <h4>Documentos cargados</h4>
               </div>
             </div>
     <table id="tabla1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
     <thead>
     <tr>
  <th>Serie fact.</th>
        <th>No. Albaran</th>
        <th>fecha </th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
 .......
        </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
    <?php
  if(isset($_FILES['file1'])){
   $Columnas = array( 'albaran', 'fecha', 'telefono',  'clientes', 'factura')
   $DBtabla = "factusol.lineas_facturadas.";
   $errores = 0;
       $ficherofinal = "/var/www/iongest/content/documentos/xls/" . $file_name ; 
   if (file_exists($ficherofinal)) { 
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($ficherofinal);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
     {  
     for ($i = 9; $i <= $numRows; $i++) 
     {
     $serie = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
     $id_factu = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
     .......
  
     $estado_e = 1;
     echo    "<tr>" .
       "<td>" . $serie . "</td>" .
       "<td>" . $id_factu . "</td>" .
       ......
       ?>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
       
       </tfoot>
      </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<..........
```

Este es la parte del programa interesante...  ¿Alguna Idea que me ayude?

Gracias a todos por leer esto ....

Comment: Cuál es el error en específico?

Comment: al llegar al boton "mostrar" debe de cargar la rutina "actualizo" que lee la excel y al final de cada linea debe de entrar en la rutina "actualizo2" que modifica la tabla "lineas_facturadas", pero me dice que no existe "actualizo"... y no se porque , vengo de otras formas de programación y estoy un poco perdido...

Comment: gracias por molestarte...

Comment: También me indica que "$ficherofinal" no existe.....

Comment: en la linea del botón "mostrar"

Comment: Lo primero que debes decirnos es si el código que muestras es una clase. Si es una clase entonces para llamar a las funciones de ella misma tienes que usar `$this`. O sea,  `$this->actualizo(...parametros...)` y `$this->actualizo2(...parametros)`.Y, viendo el lío de código que te traes, sugeriría que investigues sobre el uso de Ajax y consideres separar funciones en tu código para simplificar.

Comment: De inicio gracias por las ideas.. de segundo "la que me traigo" con el código , es por muchas razones y te diría que no son las mas adecuadas... quizás no tenga mas remedio que ir asi , probando buscando como hacerlo... que no tengo mucha idea de PHP y HTML, seguro, ni tengo tiempo para pararme e ir a una academia... pero considero que para eso me apunto a sitios como este . quiero aprender y no tengo mas remedio que hacerlo a "trompicones"..... .. de todas formas gracias de nuevo